# Free Ping/Tracert tool for Blackberry

Tags: ping, blackberry

I often use my blackberry (Storm) as a troubleshooting tool. For example, if I'm trying to determine if a website is visible from outside of the network, I just use the built in browser.

I have been trying to find a tool that would allow me to ping a remote server from the device. I already have the SSH tool (midpshh) so these days I have been logging into a remote server and pinging from there, but that's bit backwards. What I can't find is a working ping tool.

Ive seen some proprietary remote-admin tool bundles but I don't really need anything that complex. Simple network diagnostics like ping and tracert would be great to have.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I think you've bumped into one of the frustrating limitations of the BlackBerry platform. It seems like lots of people are pining for a Ping/Tracert tool for any price, much less free. I do hope that someone proves me wrong, but I don't think such a thing exists. One option that I see available to you is to use an SSH client (Possibly [MidpSSH](http://www.xk72.com/midpssh/) client) on the BB, connect to a computer on a network that you're interested in and then perform pings from there. This gives you the added benefit of being able to perform pings on a LAN since the BB has a woeful lack of a WiFi transceiver.

I could gloat about the bazillions of networking tools available to my iPhone via the AppStore, but I'm too busy scanning my network with [iNet](http://www.bananaglue.de/inet/index_e.php) and performing a wireless site survey complete with geotags using WiFiFoFum. Tee hee! =P

Answer (score 0):

Not useful for you with a Storm I realize, but:

ping is already there if you are on Wi-Fi

On a Wi-Fi device, go to Manage Connections -> Wi-Fi Options -> Wi-Fi Diagnostics.

Then hit the menu button and Ping will be in the list (along with DNS lookup).

Comment: The storm actually has that feature but it is virtually useless because of the lack of wifi support. :(

Answer (score 0):

While it's not on the Blackberry itself, you could always use http://network-tools.com.  This site has tools for ping, tracert and even http header download so you can verify a remote host from an independent third party.

Answer (score 0):

I use WinMobile device and What I fund useful is free [Putty](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/tag/putty-for-blackberry/) tool for SSH connection,
Whit putty I can made SSH connection to lot of routers which I admin.
After that I can use a lot of network tools which is already build in routers.

Comment: I now realizing that this is same answer as Nonapeptie has give already, Sometime I am so happy that finally and I can offer some good answer to the community that I have no patience to read all answers.